# How to get Role Claims in asp.net core 6 web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to get `RoleClaims` from ASP.NET CORE Identity and my code is:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllRoleClaims(string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    var role= await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var roleclaim = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
   // var roleclaim = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync((IdentityRole)role);

    return Ok(roleclaim);
}
```

It give me the error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole'

the Error is at this section:

```
var roleclaim = _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
```

The `GetClaimsAsync(role)` function does not accept the `role` and give the above error and when I use this `var roleclaim = _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync((IdentityRole)role);` for conversion it gives me another error at runtime:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole'.

Can anyone help me how to `getRoleClaims` from .net core Identity using `roleManager`?

Comment: `await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);` then foreach loop because its a list , [`have a look here`](https://dev.to/moe23/asp-net-core-rest-api-authorization-with-jwt-roles-vs-claims-vs-policy-step-by-step-5bgn)

Comment: Thank you I used  foreach loop and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
var role= await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Returns a list of role names (strings), e.g. ["admin", "user"].

Now, use the role name (string) to get the role object if your user only has one role,

```
var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role.First());
```

Then, pass the role to get the claims,

```
var roleclaim = _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario you can do as following: Therefore, it will return you the required claim.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllRoleClaims(string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

    var roleclaim = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

    return Ok(roleclaim);
}
```

**Note:** If you want to get only single claim by given email, in this scenario its better to skip looping and above way would be efficient in regards of `Big O`.

Comment: Your code return the UserClams not UserRoleClams I want to return UserRleClams from AspNetRoleClams table but your code return data from AspNetUserClams, they are two deferent table